# Qt and SQLite, error when executing query, without error message

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, sqlite

I am using Qt 5.4 and SQLite to to database operations, all other requests work, but this one doesn't seem to work and gives no error.

```
   QSqlQuery query(Globals::db);

   QString cmd = "Update VideoFile set isVisible = 0 WHERE Id  =1;";
   if(query.prepare(cmd))
       qDebug("Prepare success..."); //<-- prints out


 if (!query.exec()) {
     qDebug("Error occurred querying.");
     qDebug("%s.", qPrintable(Globals::db.lastError().text())); //<<-- prints out blank

 }
```

**Tried so far:**

o) Database: exists!

o) Query Prepare() yields True

o) When executing the same Statement in SQLite Browser. Works!

i read about a problem [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#):, that some databases have a certain delay.

*"Portability note: Some databases choose to delay preparing a query until it is executed the first time. In this case, preparing a syntactically wrong query succeeds, but every consecutive exec() will fail."* But apparently, the query is not syntactically wrong.

Comment: Did setup a DB connection? Does `QSqlDatabase::isOpen` return `true`? Does `QSqlQuery::lastError` return any errors?

Comment: The first yes, the second doesn't show any error as mentioned in the post

Comment: Do i have to add any other statement, when not inserting but setting the value of a field?

Comment: Look at what @hank wrote: "Does QSqlQuery::lastError return any errors?" - That is _not_ what your code is doing.  `QSqlDatabase::lastError()` is not the same as `QSqlQuery::lastError()`.

Comment: Execute `select * from videofile` and see if it returns anything at all - this way you will be sure that you're addressing a proper table in a proper database. If that's okay, then execute your `UPDATE` and finally execute the `SELECT` again and see if value has changed - from your application perspective. Maybe this will give you some hint about what's wrong.

Comment: I created a sample database and the snippet you provided works without any problem.